# Facebook JS SDK demanding too many permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, permissions

I have a Facebook tab set up to ask for permission for the users email - this works fine, but the dialog that comes up says '**Appname would like to access your public profile, friend list and email address.**'

This will lower participation for the app - I don't want the public profile or friend list.

Code is as follows, with fake appId:

```
 var useremail;
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '01234567890', 
            cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
              useremail=response.email;
              //Do stuff
                });
            } else {
                //No access
            }
        },{scope: 'email'});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
```

Even if I remove the email scope request, it still claims I am after the user's public profile and friend list. Not had this issue before, it used to show the friendly customisable dialog that you can preview in the Apps>Settings>Permissions area.

I can't find any other setting that could have caused this. Any ideas, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm marking this as answered, the issue is covered at http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/12/12/how-changes-to-facebooks-app-auth-process-affect-developers/

In short, in the permissions dialog shown when logging on via the Javascript SDK Facebook have renamed 'Basic info' to 'Public profile and friend list'.

We're reverting to having a manually filled email field on the Facebook competitions we do, it will probably result in more participation than being forced to throw such an ominous sounding dialog in visitors faces and having people rightfully say 'no thanks'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
```

line? Replace /me with /email and that should work.

I got this from the Graph API.

Comment: Just tried creating a brand new app, and pointing at this app's hosting but the same problem occurs, so it is definitely something at issue with this code rather than settings that have crept in elsewhere. I hate developing for Facebook, nothing stays stable for more than 6 weeks.

Comment: Hmmm. According to http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/12/12/how-changes-to-facebooks-app-auth-process-affect-developers/ Facebook, in their infinite wisdom, have renamed 'Basic info' to 'public profile and friend list'. Can someone turn this company into the next MySpace please? Maybe then no one will ask me to develop for their horrific, zero-consistency SDK. If no one knows any different, I'll mark this as answered shortly.

Comment: Dang, yeah FB is a nightmare to develop for since they keep changing. I keep hoping that since they are playing with the big dogs that they'll be smart about changing their SDK and crappy documentation, but no such luck. Looks like I'll have to go and change my app around as well :( Thanks for the link though! Sorry I couldn't be of use.